# How to redirect to another window in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a login page in my application if the user enter the login details and clicks the button the window should be disappeared and moved to another window how to do that in java swing i tried with creating frame and set visible to false but it is not working?

Comment: @Sanjeev am using gui builder

Comment: @Sanjeev JFrame loginPage=new JFrame();
            loginPage.setVisible(false);}

Comment: Now call the Constructor of Page U wish to invoke. And do add setVisible(true)

Comment: @KumarPallav its not workig

Comment: My suggestion. Learn to hand code before you try using GUI Builder. You've asked a lot of question in the last few days. And a few of them seem very basic. I strongly urge you to drop the GUI Builder and go through as much of [**Creating GUI with Swing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) as you can. Then when you feel comfortable hand coding, use the GUI builder just as a convenience tool. All of the question you ask, show no code. _"I'm using GUI Builder"_ is not an excuse for showing no code. Everyone can only make guesses to your problem.

Comment: @peeskillet sure will start work with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this

```
if("credentials are correct"){
    this.dispose();
    // call new frame that contains the page to 
    //be displayed after logging in successfully
}
```

`dispose()` method will close the current frame(`this`).

Comment: superd idea done with my doubt thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a `StartUp` class, that calls the login as `JDialog` like:

```
public class StartUp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //1- showLoginDialog
        //2- if pass, then dispose the login dialog by calling JDialog.dispose() method
        //3- show main JFrame by calling JFrame.setVisibe(true) method
    }
}
```

Comment: where to create this start up class i cant understand

Comment: OH, You need to Create it in your project. and make it the default class to run when you Run you project.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've used in this case is to create first the parent frame (the one that will be shown after login) and set him invisible. Then you can launch the login window. You must add a listener to this frame so that when it's closed as a login successful result, you make the parent frame visible.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame("Main window");
    parentFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //add content to the main frame
    parentFrame.setVisible(false);

    final JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame("Login window");
    //add content to the login frame
    loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    loginFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(final WindowEvent e) {
            super.windowDeactivated(e);
            //test if login successful
            parentFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```